# Javascript serialized POST

Tags: javascript, post

I am trying to achieve that when I call the JS function, a post request is send. In my browser I would send:

```
http://myuser:password@hc2:80/api/callAction?deviceID=185&name=turnOn
```

This works. Yet in my code it doesn't.

Important to note:
- Chrome does raise an Error: Request doesn't pass access control. If I disable this in Chrome, I doesn't display this error (yet no response from the server either).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function changestate() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.withCredentials = true;
        var user = "bassie"
        var pass = "password"
        var url = "http://hc2/api/callAction";
        var params = "deviceID=185&name=turnOff";
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + user + ":" + pass);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        alert(http.responseText);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    alert(http.responseText);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Is `hc2` the name of the server containing the web page with the Javascript?

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. The HC2 is the name of the server getting the post request (target server).

Comment: If it's not also the name of the server sending the request, you're running into cross-domain AJAX.

Comment: Correct, I believe that to be the case. CORS issues as I use two different hosts.

Comment: Do you control the server? You can have it send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers in the response.

Comment: I don't control the target server, it is a closed device that I have in my network so I am not concerned regarding cross domain security issues

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're concerned. The HTTP protocol puts the control of CORS on the server. If you can't change the server, you'll need to use a proxy on your own server to relay the request.

Comment: Aha! That explains a lot. So the target server prevents the request. So that is the reason it works in my browser, but not via a web-server performing the request. Did I understood that correctly? So I would perform a system call (i.e. a curl command) it would work?

Comment: Most server scripting languages have better ways to perform HTTP calls than running the `curl` command with `system()`. PHP has its own `curl` extension, Python has `urllib`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160747/discussion-between-bassie-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to putting the URL in the browser's location is a `GET` request, not `POST`.

Since you're sending a cross-domain request, you won't be able to read the response (unless you relay through a proxy on your origin server). So you can't read http.responseText, and can simply omit the `onreadystatechange` function; you'll just have to assume it

```
function changestate() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.withCredentials = true;
    var user = "bassie"
    var pass = "password"
    var url = "http://hc2/api/callAction";
    var params = "deviceID=185&name=turnOff";
    http.open("GET", url + "?" + params, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + user + ":" + pass);
    http.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually ended up creating a sort of like proxy. This was the main component. Not in the example (My script gets the HTTP requested) and gets the output. Below the gist of it:

```
   req = urllib.request.Request('http://hc2:80/api/callAction?param1=1&param2=2')
   credentials = ('%s:%s' % ('user', 'password'))
   encoded_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode('ascii'))
   req.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % 
   encoded_credentials.decode("ascii"))
   response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```